# Using cookies with subdomains is breaking the flash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies, subdomain

In a multi-tenant app, I've set the cookies in such a way that signing into `acme.com` or `*.acme.com` keeps the user logged in across the domain level. It's breaking the flash, however:

```
Acme::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_acme_session', domain: :all
```

Now, any changes I make on, say, `cayote.acme.com`, no longer show flash messages. Any ideas why this is happening? For changes I make on the domain level, `acme.com`, the flash remains intact.

On my dev machine I'm using `account.lvh.me:3000` for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `domain: 'lvh.me'` instead